# Read XML and create objects using LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: web-service, xml, vb.net, rest

Com o seguinte código abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <escuelas>
    <escuela>
    <estudiante>noe</estudiante>
    <fechaCreacion>2017-11-21T00:11:26.748-05:00</fechaCreacion>
    <idE>1</idE>
    <nombre>joao</nombre>
    <profesor>maria</profesor>
    </escuela>
    </escuelas>
```

> Obs: Estou trabalhando com REST em um Serviço Web, então ao agregar um
>   novo objeto o serviço me retorna um xml com todos os objetos, porém,
>   ainda não encontrei uma forma de ler esses dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabalhar com XML vc tem algumas ferramentas disponíveis no .Net Framework.

O **XPath** e o **XmlSerializer**.
No XmlSerializer vc cria uma estrutura de classes que corresponde à estrutura do XML que vc está carregando, usando anotations para determinar se os valores estão em elementos ou atributos e chama o método Deserialize da classe para carregar todas as informações para a estrutura que vc definiu. 


Se o que vc quer é simplesmente buscar um ou mais valores específicos dentro do Xml, XPath é o mais indicado. 
O Link abaixo explica como usá-lo:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-filter-on-an-attribute-xpath-linq-to-xml

Abs e bom trabalho!

Comment: Obrigado meu caro, já consegui resolver meu problema! Desculpe o atraso, era um projeto de faculdade portanto aqueles que verem essa pergunta e quiser saber como eu resolvi, só me chamar ! Abraços